# How do I disable scrolling for all but one div?

Tags: jquery

So I have a page that runs the follwing code for scrolling (copied for a nother tutorial):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('.mydiv');
    var dir = 'up'; // wheel scroll direction
    var div = 0; // current div
    $(document.body).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
            dir = 'down';
        } else {
            dir = 'up';
        }
        // find currently visible div :
        div = -1;
        divs.each(function(i){
            if (div<0 && ($(this).offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop())) {
                div = i;
            }
        });
        if (dir == 'up' && div > 0) {
            div--;
        }
        if (dir == 'down' && div < divs.length) {
            div++;
        }
        //console.log(div, dir, divs.length);
        $('html,body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: divs.eq(div).offset().top
        }, 1500);
        return false;
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('html,body').scrollTop(divs.eq(div).offset().top);
    });
});
```

But now I also have an imprint that is hidden and shows up if you press a certain button, this all works fine BUT the imprint itselfe is rather long and thus has a scrollbar of its own so that the height is 500px but the actual content inside is longer. If you now try to scroll with the mousewheel it first scrolls the background (i guess the body) and then the div of my imprint: How can I disable all scrolling for the background and have all my mousewheel commands go into the imprint div (as long as it is open)

```
overflow:hidden;
```

doesn't work as the jquery code overwrites this (and the body allready has overlfow:hidden; to make it look good)

Here is also the code that makes the imprint appear:

```
  $('.imp').click(function(){
    $('.impressum').show('slow');
});
  $('.imp-close').click(function(){
    $('.impressum').hide('slow');
});
```

Comment: Can you do a jsfiddle we can play with?

Comment: For some reason jsfiddle doesn't display my code correctly :/

Comment: Ensure you have selected jQuery from the left menu.